# How to see if an Array contains a value from another Java List in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have 1 Scala Array containing Strings and 1 Java Util List containing Strings. I want to check if value of one Array is in the other List, and set a flag accordingly.

```
def getFlag(JavaList, scalaArray): Boolean = {
  val res = JavaList.toArray.filter(x => scalaArray.contains(x))

  if (res.isEmpty)
    false
  else 
    true
}
```

the contains doesn't seem to be working. It always shows the size as 0 even when there should be a matching string and I'm not sure why.

How would I fix this or are there any other better methods of doing this? I am trying to get more familiar with Scala any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: Could you print `JavaList` and `scalaArray` prior to filtering? And possibly `JavaList.toArray`? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, it's not necessary to create a variable named `res`, then check if it's empty in an if statement, and return true or false manually. You could just return `res.isEmpty` or write the whole thing out in one line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `exists` and I would transform the **Array** into a **Set** to speed up the check.

```
// This one for 2.13+
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
// This one for 2.12-
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def getFlag(javaList: java.util.List[String], scalaArray: Array[String]): Boolean = {
  val values = scalaArray.toSet
  javaList.asScala.exists(values.contains)
}
```

If you get a `false`, then there are some errors in the strings, maybe try converting them to lower case or checking if there are invisible characters in there.

---

> I am trying to get more familiar with Scala any help is appreciated thank you

My best advice would be try to stay away from **Java** collections and from plain `Arrays`. Instead, use collections from the **Scala** library like: `List`, `Vector`, `ArraySeq`, `Set`, `Map`, etc.